# Why does polars pl.read_excel() make sometimes unknown cause error?

Tags: python-polars

polars is very fast and easy to write. However, it often raises a read error for excel & csv files with many rows.Error message:

You might want to try:

- increasing `infer_schema_length` (e.g. `infer_schema_length=10000`),
- specifying correct dtype with the `dtypes` argument
- setting `ignore_errors` to `True`,
  Original error: `remaining bytes non-empty`

Polars needs read_options to read_excel(/csv) large size rows file.

```
df = pl.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet,
     read_options={"infer_schema_length": None})
```

I try this, and could read_excel 23000 rows data file.

from polars doc:
https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/index.html
infer_schema_length : int or None
The maximum number of rows to scan for schema inference. If set to None, the full data may be scanned (this is slow). This parameter only applies if the input data is a sequence or generator of rows; other input is read as-is.

https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_excel.html#polars.read_excel
For example {"infer_schema_length": None} can be used to read the data twice, once to infer the correct output types and once more to then read the data with those types.

Comment: `Invalid xlsx file: "filepath"`. Are you sure the file path is passed to the function correctly?

Comment: In general, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: Thank you, 
Invalid xlsx file: "filepath". Are you sure the file path is passed to the function correctly? – 
Hericks
 4 hours ago

Comment: Hericks , Thank you, your advice 
"Invalid xlsx file: "filepath". Are you sure the file path is passed to the function correctly? – "

I checked that file,  and find "that file is corrupt,
I remake that file , and polars work with no trouble. 
That file was .xls and I simply rename to .xlsx by property,   but this action was not good?
Next, I chang the extension using Excel's save function from xls to xlsx.
Then, Polars works well.

Comment: data  48columns,  30000rows, 
program  read,  select,  group_by, sum, print 
csv   need  0.2 second
xlsx  need   3.4second

Comment: Glad it helped. I believe that in this case, you can close the question.

Comment: Invalid xlsx file: "filepath"=====
When using polars on Windows, the "\" in the filepath returned by the Windows system must be replaced with "\\" or "/".
However, the first time I tested "read_excel", I simply used the filepath returned by the Windows system.
That was the cause of the error that occurred when I first tested polars' "read_excel".

Comment: Another exlm excelfile, I use with Access link to sheet works well,

Comment: I usually use Microsoft Access  for Excel analysis. Link excel to Access. and use SQL, very easy by GUI.
No problems occur.
However, when  polars, some excel-file no trouble, but another file causes  error due to memory overflow.
The file size is not large. Thousands of rows and about 20 columns. When trouble, makeing half size does same.

Comment: Test xlsm , polars read_excel failed. same file  into tsv, failed.  But duckdb could read_csv, and transfer  into polars. Then, I could use polars methods.